# Link from a Wordpress page to a password protected non-Wordpress page on a subdirectory

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, password

I have a Wordpress site which contains a link to a non-WordPress (i.e. pure Html) page sitting on a subdirectory of the same domain. It all works fine at the moment but now I wish to password protect that subdirectory.

I tried adding .htaccess and .htpasswd files but then when I attempt to go to that page, instead of seeing the expected "please type a username and password" I see "This page doesn't seem to exist."

I know there are ways of adding passwords from one WordPress page to another but this issue is from WordPress to non-WordPress.

**EDIT:** As requested... the root directory contains the following four subdirectories:

- wp-content
- wp-includes
- wp-admin
- info

There is a link on the front page of the wordpress site like so:

```
Take a look at the results <a href="http://www.example.com/info/results.htm">here</a>
```

I put both the .htaccess and .htpasswd files in the "info" directory. The info directory also contains "results.htm" of course.

The \info\.htaccess file contains:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /home2/public_html/example/info/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Options -Indexes
```

the root .htaccess contains:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

If I temporarily disable the root .htaccess file by renaming it then the whole thing works. I.e. I do see the request for username and password when I try and access the /info/results.htm file.

Comment: "I tried adding .htaccess and .htpasswd files" - Please show the directives used and the location of these `.htaccess` files.

Comment: You've not shown the directives in the root (WordPress) `.htaccess` file? Does this contain just the standard WP code block (ie. front-controller)? If you temporarily rename the root `.htaccess` file (essentially disabling WP) are you presented with the username/password dialog?

Comment: "`/home2/public_html/example/info/.htpasswd`" - To clarify... your document root is `/home2/public_html/example` and not `/home2/public_html` (as one might expect)?

Comment: @MrWhite: See edits to OP. The reason for the "example" in the path is that this is actually an "addon" domain,

Comment: And you don't have any other `.htaccess` files along the file system path? eg. No `.htaccess` file directly in the `public_html` directory (which would still apply here)?

Comment: There is one directly in public_html it contains: "AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php" and a few other lines which are just comments (starting with #)

Answer (score 1):

From the information given, this "should" work as intended. Whether the directory is protected by HTTP Authentication in this way should not matter.

> I see "This page doesn't seem to exist."

I'm assuming this is a WordPress generated 404 page.

So, when the directory is "protected", it appears to be incorrectly routed through WordPress. This implies that the condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` in the parent `.htaccess` file is *failing* for some reason. This condition checks that the request does not map to a physical file before routing the request through WordPress. It "should not" matter that the directory where the file is located is protected by HTTP Authentication, since this *filesystem check* is not (or should not be) an HTTP request.

As a "workaround" you can try disabling the rewrite engine in the `/info/.htaccess` file. This prevents the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file (the WordPress front-controller) from being processed.

For example:

```
# Prevent mod_rewrite directives in parent .htaccess file(s) being processed
RewriteEngine Off

Options -Indexes

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /home2/public_html/example/info/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

> **UPDATE#1:** Sadly it didn't work. Still got the "This page doesn't seem to exist." message ... which by the way appeared to be WordPress generated

Try the following instead:

1. *Remove* the `RewriteEngine` directive added above in the `/info/.htaccess` file.
2. Add the following directives to the root `.htaccess` file *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` code block:

   ```
   # Ignore any requests to the /info/ subdirectory
   RewriteRule ^info/ - [L]
   ```

   As the code comment states, this should now explicitly *ignore* any requests to the `/info` subdirectory. The WordPress directives that follow will not be processed so WordPress will not be invoked.

> **UPDATE#2:** "RewriteRule ^ - [L]" works perfectly

In order to diagnose the URL-path that mod_rewrite is seeing when requesting `/info/results.htm` (when the directory is password protected) you can try adding the following *before* the above *modified* directive. For example:

```
# Debugging URL-path
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^UrlPath=
RewriteRule (.*) /xyz?UrlPath=$1 [R,L]

# Ignore everything... (prevents URL being routed through WP)
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

When you request `/info/results.htm` you should<sup>***1**</sup> now be redirected to `/xyz?UrlPath=<something>`. What is the `<something>` part? (NB: `/xyz` doesn't exist, so you should see an *Apache* 404 response - not a WordPress 404 response.)

<sup>(***1** - I say "should", this is on *your* system, with how it appears to be behaving. It "should" display the user/pwd dialog, but that is not happening for reasons not yet determined.)</sup>

Comment: Sadly it didn't work. Still got the "This page doesn't seem to exist." message ... which by the way appeared to be WordPress generated - it even had my site's wordpress header image above it.

Comment: Ok, something a bit weird going on here. Do you have access to the server config? I've added an alternative approach to my answer - this explicitly prevents any requests that start `/info/` from being passed to WordPress.

Comment: I don't have access to the server config. So I tried the second approach. Then, when I first clicked the link from the homepage to the info page it displayed the results.htm immediately - I then realised my username/password were probably already in the cache so I then tried again from a new "private" window (firefox)... then when I clicked the link from the homepage I got the old  "This page doesn't seem to exist." message.

Comment: Try (temporarily) changing the above `RewriteRule ^info/ - [L]` to simply `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` - this should prevent _everything_ from going through WordPress, so you _should not_ get the "This page doesn't seem to exist." msg. If that still doesn't change this behaviour then change `RewriteEngine On` to `Off` in the WordPress code block.

Comment: "RewriteRule ^ - [L]" works perfectly - I now see the request for the username and password and if I type them in I get to see my results.htm... so is this a full solution?

Comment: "so is this a full solution?" - no, since presumably your WordPress site no longer functions - or are you not using "pretty" WordPress permalinks? (If you're not using "pretty" WP permalinks then you don't actually need the `.htaccess` file in the root.) If `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` "works" then it would seem the URL-path (that mod_rewrite sees at least) does not start `info/` (no slash prefix is intentional) when you are seemingly requesting a URL of the form `/info/results.htm` - which is a puzzle. I can add more debugging info to my answer...

Comment: I've updated my answer to further help debug this. What webserver and version are you using?

Comment: I made the "xyz" edit... now the homepage does not show, instead I see "https://example.com/xyz?UrlPath=". if I directly type the url of the results file into my browser, i.e. "example.com/info/results.htm" then I see: "http://example.com/xyz?UrlPath=info/results.htm"

Comment: Browserspy.dk reports "nginx/1.14.1".

Comment: "I made the "xyz" edit... now the homepage does not show, instead I see `example.com/xyz?UrlPath=`" - Yes, that would be correct. This directive is only to try and help with debugging the problem. (The "homepage" previously displayed because the mod_rewrite directives are not required to display the homepage. But navigating to any other WordPress URL would have failed presumably?)

Comment: "if I directly type the url of the results file into my browser, i.e. `example.com/info/results.htm` then I see: `example.com/xyz?UrlPath=info/results.htm`" - Hhhmm, OK - that is what we would have expected (but `RewriteRule ^info/ - [L]` failed to work for some other reason in that case?!).

Comment: "Browserspy.dk reports "nginx/1.14.1" - Nginx might be used as a front-end proxy (and may even be contributing to this odd behaviour), however, this can't be the server software used on your application server. Nginx does not support `.htaccess`-type files (mod_rewrite etc.). I would expect you are on either: Apache 2.2, Apache 2.4 or LiteSpeed or _something else_?

Comment: The host has this software Apache 2.4.41 PHP 7.0.33 MySQL 5.6.41-84.1